# How to display a content in two-column layout in LaTeX?

Tags: latex

I am writing an article in LaTeX and I would like to display some content in two column layout. In the left column a matrix and in the right column a list of items. I have tried with tabular environment but it does not work as I want.

My question is how to create a two column area in a LeTeX document (or something similar) and be able to put certain content to left and right column? I do not want to create a two-column layout for whole document, only for part of it.

Comment: Now there is a new [StackExchange site about Tex](http://tex.stackexchange.com/) and it's derivatives specifically for these kinds of questions.

Comment: `\documentclass[11pt,twocolumn]{article}` only split the document to two parts automatically.

Answer (score 221, accepted):

Load the [multicol](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/multicol) package, like this `\usepackage{multicol}`. Then use:

```
\begin{multicols}{2}
Column 1
\columnbreak
Column 2
\end{multicols}
```

If you omit the `\columnbreak`, the columns will balance automatically.

Comment: This is great, thanks! However, I have the issue that latex sometimes automatically breaks up a column where I don't want that. Can I set something to prevent that?

Answer (score 44):

Use two [minipages](http://noodle.med.yale.edu/latex/latex2e-html/ltx-267.html).

```
\begin{minipage}[position]{width}
  text
 \end{minipage}
```

Comment: while multicol will work, and works well, if you want specific control of *what* is in the columns, then the minipage idea would probably work best.

Comment: @Mica This seems like a step away from WYSIWYM. Right?

Comment: @isomorphismes Yes I suppose it a step away from WYSIWYM... but it works.

Comment: TeX was never primarily about WYSIWYM, it is a typesetting language after all. Use Org-Mode or Markdown for WYSIWYM.